# Css or Javascript files are not working after publish on server

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, internet-explorer

When I launch the web application from Visual Studio with IE it works very fine. After publishing the app on a local server in the company It just works on Chrome and firefox. When I look at DEveloper Tool from IE, in the styles window, styles of elements which has -ms- tag (for instance -ms-transform) has a wavy red line under iti kind of indicates it does not work. But I am using IE. I hope I could explain the situation.

Paths are all like `<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>` . Scripts is a folder and it of course exists in published folder on the server.
My IE version is 11.0.9600.17278. IIS 8.0 is installed on server.

Edit: By the way some of them are not working, not all of them.

Comment: This would be css reference, not js.

Comment: I meant that all css, js and image paths are Folder/File.extention. Just gave a js example.

Comment: did you try ctrl+F5 in the browser.

Comment: @Ferenjito Of course.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 <script src="../Scripts/jquery-ui.js" />
```

also make sure your files are copying from VS when you publish it. 
Additionally if your using some sort of Authentication for users and you are denying user access to all pages through the web.config, you will need to allow users to access scripts.
This can be done by putting a web.config file in the folder Scripts allowing all anonymous users to access it.